# Crear números aleatorios sin que se repitan

Tags: java, array, algoritmos

Necesito generar números aleatorios sin que éstos se repitan.

Yo ingreso X cantidad, digamos 20, me tiene que generar un número entre 0 y 20, y al volver a ejecutar la opción que me genere otro número entre 0 y 20 sin que se repita el que ya me dio antes.

```
static int [] Crear_Arreglo (int n) {
    int [] a = new int [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = rnd.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Aquí genero números aleatorios, pero no encuentro cómo hacer lo que ya les indique.

Comment: ¿Los números son enteros? ¿Y siempre se deben generan **todos** los n números?

Comment: Si son enteros, el usuario debe ingresar al teclado los n números que el sistema me generara, estos se irán generando uno a uno, los ya generados los debe ir guardando para que no se repitan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos algoritmos para resolver lo que indicas:

1. Tener almacenados los números generados en algún lugar, quizás un `Set` (para facilitar el tiempo de búsqueda). Cuando se intente conseguir un nuevo número, verificar si el número ya existe en el `Set`, de no existir es un valor válido, de existir reintentar. Contra: no existe una forma de calcular el tiempo de generación de los números, a más números generados es muy probable que más tiempo tome obtener un nuevo número aletorio.

Ejemplo base:

```
Set<Integer> generados = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    int aleatorio = -1;
    boolean generado = false;
    while (!generado) {
        int posible = rnd.nextInt();
        if (!generados.contains(posible)) {
            generados.add(posible);
            aleatorio = posible;
            generado = true;
        }
    }
    //usa el valor de aleatorio...
}
```

2. Crear un arreglo o lista con los números deseados, ordenados, y luego desordenar los números. Luego, el método debería obtener estos números uno a uno.

Ejemplo base usando el [algoritmo de Fisher-Yates](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_Fisher-Yates):

```
//usando Java 7 o anterior
int[] numerosAleatorios = new int[20];
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    numerosAleatorios[i] = i;
}
//usando Java 8
int[] numerosAleatorios = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).toArray();
//desordenando los elementos
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = numerosAleatorios.length; i > 0; i--) {
    int posicion = r.nextInt(i);
    int tmp = numerosAleatorios[i-1];
    numerosAleatorios[i - 1] = numerosAleatorios[posicion];
    numerosAleatorios[posicion] = tmp;
}
//ya los tienes desordenados, ahora puedes usarlos
```

Comment: Los números que el sistema me generara el usuario debe ingresarlos al teclado, puede ser 20, puede ser 50, 30, etc. Los debe generar uno a uno cada vez que el usuario los pida.

Comment: @Joker en lugar de poner 20 en duro usa una variable tipo `int`. El resto del código sigue siendo el mismo.