# Números aleatorios en Java sin usar random

Tags: java-8, random

Quisiera saber como puedo mandar a imprimir numeros aleatorios en java, pero sin usar la función Random. Si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Echale un vistazo a esta consulta que se realizo hace tiempo, puede que sea lo que buscas:

[Crear números aleatorios sin que se repitan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38599/crear-n%C3%BAmeros-aleatorios-sin-que-se-repitan)